# Get Java Class represented by a String in JRuby? (without eval)

Tags: class, reflection, jruby

I want to call a static method on a Java Class in JRuby. Presently to acheive this I use:

```
class_name = "com.slackworks.naether.util.LogUtil"
clazz = eval(class_name)
clazz.setLogLevel( "debug" )
```

It seems clumsy to have to use an eval to convert the String into a Class. I have look around but cannot find a JRuby helper to take place of the `eval`.

---

The reason I need a String to converted to a Class is this is happening in a wrapper that handles requests over JRuby or RJB, depending on the Ruby runtime. If the Ruby runtime uses RJB, the call would resemble:

```
class_name = "com.slackworks.naether.util.LogUtil"
clazz = Rjb::import( class_name )
clazz.setLogLevel( "debug" )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load/get a proxy class without actually hooking it into your namespace you can use:

```
str_class = JavaUtilities.get_proxy_class("java.lang.String")
```

Please be aware: this is only useful in certain situations, use normal `java_import` if possible.

Answer (score 4):

So I stumbled upon a solution from looking at the [JRuby Wiki](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby). `Java::JavaClass.for_name` can be used to convert the String to a Java class, which can be converted to a Ruby class using `ruby_class`. Example using IRB:

```
jruby-1.6.8 :053 > math_class = Java::JavaClass.for_name("java.lang.Math").ruby_class
 => Java::JavaLang::Math 
jruby-1.6.8 :054 > math_class.floor( 10.7 )
 => 10.0
```

Comment: This works, but I believe `Java::JavaClass.for_name` is [deprecated](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/9.4.0.0/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/javasupport/JavaClass.java#L198) in JRuby 9.4. Using `JavaUtilities.get_proxy_class` ([as suggested by reto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26471591)) seems to be the non-deprecated solution for modern code.

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby? In particular, `java_import` should allow you to do this.

```
$ jruby -S irb
irb(main):001:0> java_import 'java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit'
=> [Java::JavaUtilConcurrent::TimeUnit]
irb(main):002:0> TimeUnit.values
=> java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit[NANOSECONDS, MICROSECONDS, MILLISECONDS, SECONDS, MINUTES, HOURS, DAYS]@46150133
```

In your example above, you should be able to do this:

```
require 'java'
java_import class_name
LogUtil.setLogLevel "debug"
```

Comment: The problem with java_import is on the consecutive calls, the return is nil.

Comment: @mguymon I don't understand what you're saying. Can you show me the code?

Comment: If you call java_import 'java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit' a second time, the return is nil instead of [Java::JavaUtilConcurrent::TimeUnit].

Comment: @mguymon : Sure. The `nil` tells you that it was already imported. This is BTW the same with `require`.  But we are never use in these examples the return value of `java_import`. Why do you care about it?

Comment: The goal is not `java_import` vs `require` but converting a String to Class. This is why `java_import` is not viable. Need a call that can be used multiple times and return a Class based on the String passed in.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using rails you can also use constantize.

```
"Java::JavaLang::Math".constantize
 => Java::JavaLang::Math
```